# Laravel vuejs get inital value

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vuejs2

I want to autofill my input value with the value of my server, this works if I do not use vue, but since I use vue for other reasons it does not.
Vue overrides the value with an empty string how can my vue take that value and update it in my axios post.

```
<input type="text" id="title" name="title" value="{{ $snippet->title }}" v-model="title">
```

new Vue({

```
el: '#snippet-form',

data: {
    title: '',
},

methods: {

    publishSnippet (e) {
        var self = this;
        axios.post('/snippets',  {
            title: this.title,
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log("success");
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        })
    },

},
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You have to use use [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props) which allows you to pass a value to the component. The thing is, you can't use it on Vue root instance. You need to use components.

In your `resources/assets/js/components/`, create a folder/file `SnipperForm/SnippetForm.vue`.

`SnippetForm.vue`, will be like:

```
<template>
    <form>
        <input type="text"
            id="title"
            name="title"
            v-model="title">

        <button @click.prevent="publishSnippet()">Submit</button>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            snippetTitle: {
                type: String,
                default: ''
            },
        },
        data: {
            title: '',
        },
        mounted() {
            this.title = this.snippetTitle;
        },
        methods: {
            publishSnippet () {
                axios.post('/snippets',  {
                    title: this.title,
                })
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log("success");
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                  console.log(error);
                })
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

And finally, in your `app.js`:

`Vue.component('snippet-form', require('SnippetForm/SnippetForm.vue'));`

And your, again, in your `app.js`, edit your Vue instance:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

And in your blade view, use the SnippetForm.vue component like:

`<snippet-form snippet-title="{{ $snippet->title }}"><snippet-form>`

Comment: Error inside the mounted() this is a reserved word

Comment: @Hensen Sorry, instead of `mounted:` it should be `mounted()`. Answer fixed.

Comment: hi, still missing something the value is not shown in the view thus I do not get any errors in my console

Comment: @Hensen Can you double check the props is written `snippetTitle`, the mounted() is using `this.snippetTitle` and finally the <input> tag to have `snippet-title`? If all is OK, download Vue Developer Tools (Chrome/FF extension) and see where the value is.

Comment: Hi the snippet-title has the correct value, the code looks [like](https://kopy.io/gNWBQ) this now it just does not show the value

Comment: @Hensen I had totally missed the idea that we are dealing with a *root instance* of Vue. It's... not optimal to use props on the instance. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Is there I way to make it work without creating a component? like directly in my instance?

Comment: @Hensen It's possible but not advisable. Google 'props on vue root instance'.